# How to connect Python consumer to AWS MSK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I'm trying to connect my python consumer to AWS MSK cluster. how can I do that?

Have an AWS MSK Cluster running
I'm trying consume message from the MSK cluster using python and kafka python.

error I'm getting

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "consumer.py", line 23, in <module>
    for message in consumer:
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1193, in __next__
    return self.next_v2()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1201, in next_v2
    return next(self._iterator)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 1116, in _message_generator_v2
    record_map = self.poll(timeout_ms=timeout_ms, update_offsets=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 655, in poll
    records = self._poll_once(remaining, max_records, update_offsets=update_offsets)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/consumer/group.py", line 675, in _poll_once
    self._coordinator.poll()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/coordinator/consumer.py", line 270, in poll
    self.ensure_coordinator_ready()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/coordinator/base.py", line 258, in ensure_coordinator_ready
    self._client.poll(future=future)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 582, in poll
    self._maybe_connect(node_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/client_async.py", line 392, in _maybe_connect
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 429, in connect
    if self._try_handshake():
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kafka/conn.py", line 508, in _try_handshake
    self._sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you searched for "Python Kafka" in a search engine?

Comment: Currently I have Kafka running in EC2 and have python consumer listening on multiple topics and processing.

But I need to run AWS MSK Cluster and connect to it.

Comment: So change the Kafka connection address in your Python code to the MSK cluster address. If that's not working, add more info in your question.

Comment: that's not working and that's  reason the question here...

Comment: If it's not working, then provide the error message in your question. It's probably not a Python issue at all, but an AWS network configuration issue, so you need to provide that information as well.

Comment: then help me with procedure to configure the network!
and I'm not getting any error message it's simply not connecting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229221/discussion-between-sanker-and-mark-b).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using kafka-python:

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    topic_name = 'example-topic'

    consumer = KafkaConsumer(topic_name, auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                             bootstrap_servers=['kafka2:9092'], api_version=(0, 10), consumer_timeout_ms=1000)
    for msg in consumer:
        print(msg.value)

    if consumer is not None:
        consumer.close()
```

---

```
from time import sleep

from kafka import KafkaProducer

# publish messages on topic
def publish_message(producer_instance, topic_name, key, value):
    try:
        key_bytes = bytes(key, encoding='utf-8')
        value_bytes = bytes(value, encoding='utf-8')
        producer_instance.send(topic_name, key=key_bytes, value=value_bytes)
        producer_instance.flush()
        print('Message ' + key + ' published successfully.')
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception in publishing message')
        print(str(ex))

# establish kafka connection
def connect_kafka_producer():
    _producer = None
    try:
        _producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['kafka1:9092'])
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception while connecting Kafka')
        print(str(ex))
    finally:
        return _producer

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kafka_producer = connect_kafka_producer()
    x = 0
    while True:
        publish_message(kafka_producer, 'raw_recipes', str(x), 'This is message ' + str(x))
        x += 1
    
    if kafka_producer is not None:
            kafka_producer.close()
```

Comment: with AWS MSK it's not working