# Connecting to AWS MSK Kafka from my laptop: NoBrokersAvailable

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-msk

I am having trouble connecting to AWS MSK Kafka (with  with **Access Control Method** configured to **None**) from my laptop, error is: **NoBrokersAvailable**

I am using **plaintext** conn over port **9092**:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer 
kafka_brokers = [ "xxx.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092","xxx.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092","xxx.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092" ]
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_brokers)
```

**Ref:** AWS MSK - plaintext broker port **9092**, TLS 9094
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/client-access.html

I tried three things (Which did not help):

a. Under my VPC default security group added inbound+outbound source/destination over 9092+9094 source/dest 0.0.0.0/0

b. Tried run over AWS Client VPN following instructions below:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/cvpn-getting-started.html#cvpn-getting-started-certs
- Instructions to generate Certs:
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/client-authentication.html#mutual
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bv70DoHDDCY

c. Turn off Firewall on my laptop

I see some others asking similar questions: [How to connect Python consumer to AWS MSK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375337/how-to-connect-python-consumer-to-aws-msk)

Some folks suggesting it's simply **not-supported** for clients on local machines/laptop to connect to AWS MSK: [How can I access my AWS MSK managed kafka queue from my local machine and EC2 instances in other regions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54401952/how-can-i-access-my-aws-msk-managed-kafka-queue-from-my-local-machine-and-ec2-in)
Is this true/official?

I'm thinking create **EIP (Elastic IP)** https://repetitive.it/aws-msk-how-to-expose-the-cluster-on-the-public-network/?lang=en
Then somehow associate with broker domain names xxx.kafka.ap-east-1.amazonaws.com (but not sure how) and configure inbound outbound rules.

But I haven't been able to find anything that helps.

I'm on my wits end, this problem already consumed whole day. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked if the security groups are setup correctly and allowing traffic to your laptop. Also can you confirm if the brokers are in public or private subnet?

Comment: They are in Public subnet. And I configured inbound + outbound rules to allow 9092/9094, no luck.

Comment: I would suggest create an ec2 instance and then try connecting using that to your msk cluster.

Comment: Last I checked, if the advertised listeners (and firewall) is correctly configured, you can connect to any broker from any network... If you use `kafkacat -L` on your brokers, what addresses do they give? Can you telnet those addresses from outside of AWS?

Comment: did you manage to resolve this issue? I'm having the same ..... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It won't be possible to directly connect to MSK brokers from you laptop . Although MSK listeners exposes a public DNS name, it actually resolves to a private IP of the MSK broker. So since you are not within the VPC, you cannot reach the private IP.

The cheapest option to achieve this is to setup
[AWS Client VPN endpoint.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpn/latest/clientvpn-admin/what-is.html)

(edited) Observed you have already tried the client VPN, what did not work? I am using it.

(edited: this is now available in MSK)

Comment: Amazon has recently allowed public access to MSK brokers: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/public-access.html